# how can i recursively track empty folders and put an .keep file in it?

Tags: git, powershell

In order to push empty folders into git, 
i want to use a recursive windows command to track those empty folders and put a ".keep" file in them.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you tracking folders?

Comment: I have some empty folders which are essential to my project,
by default, git doesnt push empty folders - thats why i need to track those folders and fill them with ".keep" file.

Comment: I understand the desired solution, I don't understand the need to keep track of empty folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this powershell script to populate all empty folders with .keep

```
(gci . -r | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | ? {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0} | foreach-object { New-Item (Join-Path $($_.FullName) ".keep")}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me !